# Android Studio Kotlin : App freezes when trying to read from inputStream (Bluetooth)

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth

So im completely new to Android Studio and Kotlin. I have been following videos as well as looking over the Bluetooth overview from developer.android.com. I am really lost in trying to continuously read data from the inputBuffer, and have no idea where to start. I am able to send data successfully through the bluetooth, but whenever I try to continuously listen for data, the app freezes. Could anyone help elaborate or help step through the process for doing this?

```
package com.example.airboard

import android.app.ProgressDialog
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket
import android.content.Context
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Handler
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.control_layout.*
import org.jetbrains.anko.toast
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*

class ControlActivity: AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        var m_myUUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
        var m_bluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null
        lateinit var m_progress: ProgressDialog
        lateinit var m_bluetoothAdapater: BluetoothAdapter
        var m_isConnected: Boolean = false
        lateinit var  m_address: String
        private val mmBuffer: ByteArray = ByteArray(1024)
        private const val TAG = "MY_APP_DEBUG_TAG"
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.control_layout)
        m_address = intent.getStringExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS)!!
        ConnectToDevice(this).execute()

        control_led_on.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("1") }
        control_led_off.setOnClickListener { sendCommand("2") }
        control_led_disconnect.setOnClickListener { disconnect() }
        listen.setOnClickListener { listen() }
    }
    private fun listen() {
        var numBytes: Int // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
        //while (true) {
            // Read from the InputStream.
            numBytes = try {
                m_bluetoothSocket!!.inputStream.read(mmBuffer)
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e)
                //break
            }
            toast(numBytes)
            // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.

       // }
    }
   private fun sendCommand(input: String){
        if (m_bluetoothSocket != null){
            try {
                m_bluetoothSocket!!.outputStream.write(input.toByteArray())
                Log.i("data", "sending..")
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                Log.i("data", "couldn't send")
                }
                return

            }

    }
    private fun disconnect(){
        if (m_bluetoothSocket != null){
            try {
                m_bluetoothSocket!!.close()
                m_bluetoothSocket = null
                m_isConnected = false
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
        finish()
    }

    private class ConnectToDevice(c: Context) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){
        private var connectSuccess: Boolean = true
        private val context: Context

        init {
            this.context = c
        }
        override fun onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute()
            m_progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Connecting...", "please wait")
        }
        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?) : String? {
            try {
                if (m_bluetoothSocket == null || !m_isConnected){
                    m_bluetoothAdapater = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
                    val device: BluetoothDevice = m_bluetoothAdapater.getRemoteDevice(m_address)
                    m_bluetoothSocket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(m_myUUID)
                    BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery()
                    m_bluetoothSocket!!.connect()

                }
            } catch (e: IOException){
                connectSuccess = false
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return null
        }
        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            if(!connectSuccess){
                Log.i("data", "couldn't connect")
            } else {
                m_isConnected = true
                Log.i("data", "connected")
            }
            m_progress.dismiss()


        }

    }
}
```

Digging through some other questions, maybe ASyncTask is not a good option for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Android runs code in the UI thread by default. So you cant use while(true) in the main thread or the UI will freeze. Instead, do this task in a separate thread. You can extend the [Thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#:%7E:text=The%20other%20way%20to%20create,when%20creating%20Thread%20%2C%20and%20started.) class and check for incoming messages inside the run() method of the class. Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread#:%7E:text=The%20other%20way%20to%20create,when%20creating%20Thread%20%2C%20and%20started.) for more info.

Comment: so I would just add in a thread class and listen in the fun run?

Comment: yes. that would be sufficient. Here's how I did it years ago, It's in java but you will get the idea. https://github.com/atick-faisal/Bluetooth-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/googleplex/bluetoothcommunication/MainActivity.java

Comment: Ahh that worked. So I am able to successfully receive data from my arduino board. How would I go about converting that data to a string?

Comment: I tried using .obtainMessage but ends up crashing the app